# Aborting wget on file found (Windows)

Tags: wget

I am trying to use wget for Windows (on Windows 7) to find and download a file that I don't know the full name of (I have a partial name, and I know the form of the unknown part of the name). I am using an input file with a list of the possible file names, and I want to abort wget when the file is found (the rest of the possibilities will give 404 errors). How can I cause wget to abort automatically when that one file is found?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: The following is the command I used.  It works to (attempt to) download the file, but I'm trying to make it stop as soon as it finds the file. I was thinking of trying -Q to abort wget when the file is found, but the files I'm searching for are not all the same size.  The input file contains several thousand possible file names.  'd:\wget\wget -a log.txt -t1 -w2 -nv -Q25k --random-wait -user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 Firefox/4.0.1" --input-file=1aaa.txt'

Comment: Anyone?  Is it not possible to do what I'm asking about?